# Not able to get custom directive attribute value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've a custom directive called "mycomponent".

```
restrict: 'AE',     
templateUrl: 'template.html',
scope:{
    sTransactionType: '=transactionType',
    sStorageVariable: '=storageVariable'                
},
link: function(scope, element, attrs){              
    console.log("attrs.transactionType:: "+attrs.transactionType);
    console.log("scope.sTransactionType:: "+scope.sTransactionType);
```

And markup as:

```
<my-component transaction-Type="FundTransfer" storage-Variable="FundTransferToday"></my-component>
```

Now, when I try to access the value of attributes `transaction-Type` and `storage-Variable` in `link` function of directive, it returns `undefined`.
Values can be accessed by `attrs.transactionType` but not able to get it with `scope.sTransactionType`.

I tried to change attribute name, scope varibale name.

**How do I get custom directive attribute values in scope variables ?**

**Updated code:**

```
var fundtransfer = angular.module("fundtransfer",['mydirectives']);
var controllers = {};
controllers.cntFundTransfer = function($scope, $rootScope){
}

var mydirectives = angular.module("mydirectives",['Constants']);
mydirectives.directive('myComponent', function($rootScope){
restrict: 'AE',     
templateUrl: 'template.html',
scope:{
    sTransactionType: '=transactionType',
    sStorageVariable: '=storageVariable'                
},
link: function(scope, element, attrs){              
    console.log("scope.sTransactionType:: "+scope.sTransactionType);
}
}

<my-component transaction-type="FundTransfer" storage-variable="FundTransferToday"></my-component>
```

Comment: Are your attributes supposed to be bound to the scope? Or are they just string values? If they are just string values then you need to use `@` in your directive scope definition

Comment: @user2341963- yes attributes are supposed to bound to the scope.

Comment: In your directive, are you expecting `scope.sTransactionType` to be the string `"FundTransfer"` or to be the scope variable `FundTransfer`? There is a big difference because there is no `FundTransfer` in the controller code you provided

Comment: @user2341963- In directive I am expecting `scope.sTransactionType` to be the string "FundTransfer". I changed "=" with "@" and it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your attribute naming is wrong.

all should be in lowercase

try like this

```
<my-component transaction-type="FundTransfer" storage-variable="FundTransferToday"></my-component>
```

**JS**

```
restrict: 'AE',     
templateUrl: 'template.html',
scope:{
    sTransactionType: '=transactionType',
    sStorageVariable: '=storageVariable'                
},
link: function(scope, element, attrs){              
    console.log("scope.sTransactionType:: "+scope.sTransactionType);
}
```

Comment: Tried with all attribute names in lowercase. Still not able to get its value in scope variable.

Comment: the code is pretty long. May I know where should look into controller for the problem ?

Comment: take a look  on `$scope.FundTransfer` in your controller

Comment: @ChakoDesai, Please see [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/E4qWI4), i have made it for you so you can identify what exactly you are missing in your controller.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi- I want the value of attribute in scope variable of a directive and so I need to use "@" instead of "=". Thanks.

Comment: @ChakoDesai `=` is two way binding and `@` will pass the value only